# Failure in Pointer Dereferencing in C while using same function and variable

Tags: c, printf, c-strings, variadic-functions, function-parameter

I am trying to using C to work with files with different extensions. So this is the code that I have written.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <conio.h>

void mvjpg(char *arg);
void mvpng(char *arg);
void wincmd(const char *c,...);

int main(int argc,char **argv){
   char *ext;

   for(int i=1;i<argc;i++){
       ext=strrchr(argv[i],'.');
       if(ext == NULL)
           continue;

       if(strcmp(ext,".jpg")==0)
            mvjpg(argv[i]);

       if(strcmp(ext,".png")==0)
            mvpng(argv[i]);
   }

   return 0;
}

void mvjpg(char *arg){

//Do tasks such as ...
    wincmd("move %s Done\\ ",arg);  //Here this runs properly
    printf("%s\n\n",arg);           //This also outputs the file name
    wincmd("copy %s JPGs\\ ",arg);  //Here the value is gibberish
    printf("%s\n\n",arg);           //This too outputs the file name
   

}

void mvpng(char *arg){
     //Do tasks such as ...
}


void wincmd(const char *c,...){
    char cmd[50];
    sprintf(cmd,c);
    printf("%s\n",cmd);
    system(cmd);
}
```

The Output is:

```
D:\Folder1>mv new.jpg
move new.jpg Done\
        1 file(s) moved.
new.jpg

copy 6Q½6ⁿ JPGs\
The system cannot find the file specified.
new.jpg
```

Why is one pointer working in first and in other it is not. The value of pointer is not altered between those commands.

Comment: Such a call sprintf(cmd,c);  has undefined behavior because the argument that corresponds to the conversion specifier %s is absent.

Comment: The function you're looking for is `vsprintf()`. It allows you to call `sprintf()` with a variadic argument list that you received in `wincmd()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear why you are using a variable argument list.

It would be much simpler to declare the function like

```
void wincmd( const char *fmt, const char *s );
```

and within the function to write

```
sprintf( cmd, fmt, s);
```

Nevertheless this call

```
sprintf(cmd,c);
```

invokes undefined behavior because there is not specified the third argument that corresponds to the conversion specification `&s` that is present in the string `c`.

You need to include header `<stdarg.h>` that is designed to deal with variable argument lists and process the unnamed argument using macros defined in the header.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void wincmd( const char *c, ... ) {
    char cmd[50];

    va_list arg;

    va_start( arg, c );

    const char *p = va_arg( arg, const char *);

    sprintf( cmd, c, p );

    va_end( arg );

    puts( cmd );
}

int main( void )
{
    const char *s = "move %s Done\\ ";
    const char *t = "new.jpg";

    wincmd( s, t );

    s = "copy %s JPGs\\ ";

    wincmd( s, t );
}
```

The program output is

```
move new.jpg Done\
copy new.jpg JPGs\
```